# How can I convert an array of XML elements to a sequence?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an issue caused by mediating from XML to JSON and back again, the issue is that the library I am required to use doesn't do a great job with JSON arrays.  Essentially the result of the mediation is:

```
<Continents>
    <ContinentName>
        <element>North America</element>
        <element>Asia</element>
    </ContinentName>
</Continents>
```

But what I want is a sequence of continent names:

```
<Continents>
    <ContinentName>North America<ContinentName>
    <ContinentName>Asia<ContinentName>
<Continents>
```

Is there a way to do this easily enough in XSL?

Thanks,

Ian

Adding a couple of better examples showing the whole document.  Sadly the answer to the question about whether this is generic or specific, is that it's specific.  The  tags are inserted by the JSON library we're using:

Example 1, simple structure, although in this case the Animals/element nodes simply need to be renamed to , this is easy.  It's the continents piece I'm confused by.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Animals>
    <element>
        <SpeciesName>Grizzly Bear</SpeciesName>
        <Continents>
            <ContinentName>
                <element>North America</element>
                <element>Asia</element>
                <element>Europe</element>
            </ContinentName>
        </Continents>
        <Population>867</Population>
        <href>http://fazio.loc/rest/animal/5a559e67-475b-41e8-9fdc-00359be1d4e2</href>
        <Id>5a559e67-475b-41e8-9fdc-00359be1d4e2</Id>
    </element>
    <element>
        <SpeciesName>Black Bear</SpeciesName>
        <IdentificationDate>1897-10-20</IdentificationDate>
        <Continents>
            <ContinentName>
                <element>North America</element>
                <element>Europe</element>
            </ContinentName>
        </Continents>
        <Population>11054</Population>
        <href>http://fazio.loc/rest/animal/f2e020e4-93ab-4d9b-b7b2-63082e2eaf06</href>
        <Id>f2e020e4-93ab-4d9b-b7b2-63082e2eaf06</Id>
    </element>
</Animals>
```

Example 2 is more complex because the LineItem array can contain one, or more than one element with different results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Orders>
    <element>
        <Description>First Order</Description>
        <Status>New</Status>
        <TotalCost>$45</TotalCost>
        <LineItems>
            <LineItem>
                <Name>Socks</Name>
                <Price>$15</Price>
                <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                <Total>$45</Total>
            </LineItem>
        </LineItems>
        <href>http://fazio.loc/rest/orderStatus/0d06dc7d-2491-4fa9-9e49-921b4cb9934a</href>
        <Id>0d06dc7d-2491-4fa9-9e49-921b4cb9934a</Id>
    </element>
    <element>
        <Description>First Order</Description>
        <Status>New</Status>
        <TotalCost>$80</TotalCost>
        <LineItems>
            <LineItem>
                <element>
                    <Name>Socks</Name>
                    <Price>$15</Price>
                    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                    <Total>$45</Total>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <Name>Pants</Name>
                    <Price>$35</Price>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Total>$35</Total>
                </element>
            </LineItem>
        </LineItems>
        <href>http://fazio.loc/rest/orderStatus/c929e8bc-054a-4ffc-86b9-b42af63d5537</href>
        <Id>c929e8bc-054a-4ffc-86b9-b42af63d5537</Id>
    </element>
  </Orders>
```

I really hate to do this, but I have a variant on these messages for which the proposed solution doesn't work.  This is where the inner  aren't quite as deep.  i.e. the doc looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Order 
        xmlns="http://demo.soa.com/order/1.0">
        <Description >First Order</Description>
        <Status >New</Status>
        <TotalCost >$80</TotalCost>
        <LineItems >
            <LineItem>
                <element>
                    <Name>Socks</Name>
                    <Price>$15</Price>
                    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                    <Total>$45</Total>
                </element>
                <element>
                    <Name>Pants</Name>
                    <Price>$35</Price>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Total>$35</Total>
                </element>
            </LineItem>
        </LineItems>
        <href >http://fazio.loc/rest/orderStatus/c929e8bc-054a-4ffc-86b9-b42af63d5537</href>
        <Id >c929e8bc-054a-4ffc-86b9-b42af63d5537</Id>
    </Order>
```

I can't understand what's different, but in this case, the  don't seem to be matching and so are not being replaced.

Comment: There is no concept of *array* in XML or XSLT. It's quite simple actually to convert the first XML into the second one.

Comment: Is that example you provided a general one? Are the inner elements actually called `element`?

Comment: I hadn't seen the update. I'm fixing the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[child::element][parent::*]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <xsl:element name="{name(parent::*)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT stylesheet contains three templates. The first one is called an *identity transform* because it simply copies any nodes (attributes, namespaces, comments, processing instructions and elements) from the source tree to the result tree.

The second template *skips* copying the element *if* it has an `element` child *and* if it is not the root node (it has a parent). The inner *arrays* follow a pattern `Continents/ContinentName/element`, `LineItems/LineItem/element` but that is different with the root element: `Orders/element` (and not `Orders/Order/element` or something similar). To compensate that, the element is duplicated so the resulting XML is well-formed.

The third template matches `element`, and copies in its place the name of the `parent` element (which was skipped in the second template.

Here are some working fiddles which you can experiment with online:

1. **[Fiddle no. 1](http://xsltransform.net/3Nqn5Yo/1)**
2. **[Fiddle no. 2](http://xsltransform.net/b4GWVm/3)**

**EDIT 1 - Changing the name of an element**: Since there is no `Order` or `Animal` in the source, if the root is to be `Orders/Order` and not `Orders/Orders`, we can fabricate the element name copying from the parent and cutting the `s` off (of course, it won't work so nicely with collections such as `Wolves/Wolf`). Just add this template to the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="element[parent::*[not(parent::*)]]">
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(parent::*),1,string-length(name(parent::*))-1)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This template selects `element` nodes whose parent does not have a parent (parent is *root* node) and replaces it with the name of the parent minus the last character (if parent is `Animals`, it will create `Animal`; if parent is `Root`, it will create `Roo`)

**[Fiddle no. 3](http://xsltransform.net/6qM2e2q/1)**

**EDIT 2 - Adding a default namespace**: To add a default namespace to the entire document, you just need 1) add `xmlns="your-namespace"` to `<xsl:stylesheet>` and 2) to match root and create an `<xsl:element>` providing the same namespace in the `namespace` attribute. Just add this template to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element namespace="your-namespace" name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**[Fiddle no. 4](http://xsltransform.net/948Fn5s)**

**EDIT 3 - Dealing with an existing namespace**: Your last example doesn't work because *it already declares a namespace*. Any unprefixed element selectors in the stylesheet are considered as belonging to *no namespace*. To select the `element` element from your source, which belongs to `{http://demo.soa.com/order/1.0}:element` you would have to declare that namespace (again) in the stylesheet, this time with a prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://demo.soa.com/order/1.0"       <!-- for the output tree -->
                xmlns:demo="http://demo.soa.com/order/1.0"> <!-- for use in XPath input -->
```

And *prefix* all *explicit* selections. In your stylesheet, all elements are being selected using wildcards *except* `element`. So you just have to prefix the occurrences of `element`:

```
<xsl:template match="*[child::demo:element][parent::*]"> ...
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="demo:element">
```

and anywhere else the `element` appears in the extra templates that were added in the edits.

That is *usually* the recommended solution. In your case, since the stylesheet has to deal with different sources, *which might be in different namespaces* and the `element` element shouldn't not really part of it (it's a foreign object introduced by other software), then the *best* approach is probably to *ignore* the namespace. You can do that using XPath by selecting the node using wildcards, and then comparing to its *local name* in a predicate.

You just need to replace *every* occurrence of `element` with:

```
*[local-name()='element']
```

for example:

```
<xsl:template match="*[child::*[local-name()='element']][parent::*]">
```

(BTW `child::element` and `element` mean the same thing: I just use it sometimes when I want to make the axis explicit for clarity, but you can remove it)

**[Fiddle no. 5](http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbw/1)**

If you will *always* have a namespace in your source, and you just want to *copy it* to the result, this stylesheet will not do that for you. You still have to declare it in the stylesheet. There *is* a solution, however, which consists on using the `namespace::` axis to copy the namespaces declared in the source to the result when creating each new element:

```
<xsl:element namespace="{namespace::*}" name="...">...
```

This solution *will fail if you do not have a default namespace* declared in your source.

**[Fiddle no. 6](http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbw/4)**

Comment: Very clever generic solution!

Comment: Very close, but it's resulting in and extra layer of ContinentName: <Continents><ContinentName><ContinentName>North America</ContinentName><ContinentName>Asia</ContinentName><ContinentName>Europe</ContinentName></ContinentName></Continents>

Comment: Really close now, but the outer structure isn't quite right.  It should be an <Orders> document with a sequence of <Order> objects in it.  Like <Orders><Order>....</Order><Order>...</Order></Orders>

Comment: I actually doubled the `<Orders>` as I explained above because it was resulting in a malformed XML (the pattern was different for the root `element` children.) Since there is no `Order` in the source, you can fabricate one. I will add that to the answer too.

Comment: Even closer, not sure if it'll be possible to keep this completely generic.  The issue is that the inner sequence is a sequence of <Order> not <Orders>.  So the structure is: <Orders><Order>....</Order><Order>...</Order></Orders>

Comment: Ok. It should work at least with these examples, and you will have a starting point to adapt it for the others.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much.  One last thing I'm struggling with which should be trivial is how to add a namespace declaration to the root element.  Everything I've tried seems to cause issues elsewhere.  The namespace should be http://xyzcorp.com/animal/1.0.

Comment: I guess to be more clear what I want to do is to make the whole document be in a default namespace <Animals xmlns="....">.  When I try various things, some of the elements inherit and other don't.  Not sure why.

Comment: You just need to add a template matching the root node printing it with a `xmlns` attribute, *or* write a template that uses `<xs:element>` instead of copy and add your namespace to its `namespace` attribute.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, and add a `xmlns='your-namespace'` to `<xsl:stylesheet>` !

Comment: Man I really feel like I'm abusing your skills now.  I added one more example above of a slightly different structure where the <elements> aren't matching and I don't know why.

Comment: It seems to be because of the namespace node. If the source already has a namespace, you will have to either register it or ignore it to select using XPath. Since only `element` is being called explicitly in the stylesheet, it should work if you replace each occurrence of `element` or `child::element` in the stylesheet with `*[local-name()='element']` (which selects the node ignoring the namespace)

Comment: You're unreal.  Fantastic stuff, thanks so much.  I need more points so I can upvote this...